# Как перевести строку в дикшинари Swift ?

Tags: swift

Задача состоит в том, чтоб подсчитать частоту появления каждого слова в заданном пользователем предложении. Хочу это реализовать через дикшинари: 1.Перевести каждое уникальное слово предложения в ключ. 
2.Для значений использовать частоту появления слов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Свифте это оптимальней всего реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для оптимальной реализации данной задачи можно воспользоваться классом `NSCountedSet`.
Он сам реализует подсечет повторений элементов: метод `count(for:)`

Так же можно сделать это самостоятельно используя простой `Dictionary`

Пример кода:

```
// Ваша строка
let s = "Hello, World! Hello" 

let space: Character = " "

let nonLettersAndNumbers = NSCharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted

// Убираем запятые и прочие ненужные символы
let sWithOmittedSymbos = s.components(separatedBy: nonLettersAndNumbers).joined(separator: String(space))

// Разделяем строку на массив слов
let splittedS = sWithOmittedSymbos.split(separator: space).map { String($0) }
```

Подсчет с использованием `NSCountedSet`:

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet()

for word in splittedS {
    countedSet.add(word)
}

for key in countedSet {
    let count = countedSet.count(for: key)
    print("\(key) count \(count)")
}
```

Подсчет с использованием обычного `Dictionary`:

```
var countDict: [String: Int] = [:]

for word in splittedS {

    if let _ = countDict[word] {
        countDict[word]! += 1
    } else {
        countDict[word] = 1
    }

}

for (key, value) in countDict {
    print("\(key) count \(value)")
}
```

Как вы можете заметить реализация с `NSCountedSet` выглядит гораздо лучше